# If I wanted to quote a joke from a website in verbatim in a formal academic essay, how would I do that?

Tags: citations, writing, plagiarism

The assignment is to evaluate humor in movies. I am unsure how to incorporate a joke quote in there. Would it be classified as plagiarism?

Quote: “I have an Epi-Pen. My friend gave it to me as he was dying. It seemed very important to him that I have it.”

Answer (score 5):

> If I wanted to quote a joke from a website in verbatim in a formal academic essay, how would I do that?

The same way you use text taken verbatim from any source.